# Comparing values in two files

Tags: bash, shell

I am comparing two files, each having one column and n number of rows.

file 1

vincy
alex
robin

file 2

Allen
Alex
Aaron
ralph
robin

if the data of file 1 is present in file 2 it should return 1 or else 0, in a tab seprated file.

Something like this

vincy  0
alex    1
robin   1

What I am doing is

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `cat file1 `
do
cat file2 | awk '{ if ($1=="'$i'") print 1 ; else print 0 }'>>binary
done
```

the above code is not giving me the output which I am looking for.

Kindly have a look and suggest correction.

Thank you

Comment: I think you're comparing everything in file one to the first line in file two.

Comment: its a comparison of a set with a dictionary, wether the elements of a set are present in a dictionary or not.

Comment: Useless use of cat. `awk ... < file2 >> binary`

Comment: @Jens Or, even simpler, `awk '{...}' file2 >> binary`

Comment: Your inputs have mixed case -- expecting `Alex` and `alex` to match -- is this indeed a requirement?

Comment: Thank you all for the answers... But could anyone try to fix my original script. .... even if it is silly ... or redundant .... can it be fixed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should do it.

Take a close look to the `BEGIN` and `END` sections.

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -f binary
for i in $(cat file1); do
     awk 'BEGIN {isthere=0;} { if ($1=="'$i'") isthere=1;} END { print "'$i'",isthere}' < file2 >> binary
done
```

Comment: the second column of the output is good but the value in the first column is repetition of the last value in file2.

Comment: And I called two passes _total_ silly? Starting up a new awk for each line in file1... ugh.

Comment: That's correct. I just proposed a fixed version of original script.

Comment: Another useless use of cat.  Use `$(<file1)` instead.

Comment: @TimPote Is `$(<file)` POSIX shell syntax?

Comment: Ah right. I usually mentally translate "bash" to "sh" because 99% of questions tagged "bash" should be tagged "shell" because bashisms are not needed. (The "all the world's a bash" attitude [mostly out of ignorance] sometimes gets on my nerves :-) Everybody should be using zsh anyway and SEE THE LIGHT :-) :-) :-)

Comment: Using a process substitution instead of cat hardly avoids UUOC.  It's just a useless use of process substitution!  The problem with UUOC is that it needlessly spawns another process, and changing the syntax doesn't fix the problem.  This type of loop, if it cannot be avoided, should be written `while read i; do ... ; done < file1`

Comment: `for` is almost always the wrong way to iterate over the contents of a file. `while read -r line ... done < file` is the correct way. Instead of embedding shell variables in an awk command using complex quoting, you should use `-v` variable passing.

Answer (score 2):

The simple awk solution:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{ seen[$0]=1 } NR!=FNR{ print $0 " " seen[$0] + 0}' file2 file1
```

A simple explanation:  for the lines in file2, NR==FNR, so the first action is executed and we simply record that a line has been seen.  In file1, the 2nd action is taken and the line is printed, followed by a space, followed by a "0" or a "1", depending on if the line was seen in file2.

Comment: Doesn't match "Alex" and "alex" as shown in the question. Nice use of coercion! You can use a comma instead of `" "`.

Answer (score 2):

AWK *loves* to do this kind of thing.

```
awk 'FNR == NR {a[tolower($1)]; next} {f = 0; if (tolower($1) in a) {f = 1}; print $1, f}' file2 file1
```

Swap the positions of file2 and file1 in the argument list to make file1 the dictionary instead of file2.

When `FNR` (the record number in the current file) and `NR` (the record number of all records so far) are equal, then the first file is the one being processed. Simply referencing an array element brings it into existence. This sets up the dictionary. The `next` instruction reads the next record.

Once `FNR` and `NR` aren't equal, subsequent file(s) are being processed and their data is looked up in the dictionary array.

Answer (score 1):

The `comm` command exists to do this kind of comparison for you.

The following approach does only one pass and scales well to very large input lists:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read; do
        if [[ $REPLY = $'\t'* ]] ; then
                printf "%s\t0\n" "${REPLY#?}"
        else
                printf "%s\t1\n" "${REPLY}"
        fi
done < <(comm -2 <(tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]' <file1 | sort) <(tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]' <file2 | sort))
```

See also [BashFAQ #36](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/036), which is directly on-point.

Comment: Does it make sense to change the case of the files after sorting?

Answer (score 1):

There are several decent approaches. You can simply use [line-by-line set math](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/036):

```
{
    grep -xF -f file1 file2 | sed $'s/$/\t1/'
    grep -vxF -f file1 file2 | sed $'s/$/\t0/'
} > somefile.txt
```

Another approach would be to simply combine the files and use uniq -c, then just swap the numeric column with something like awk:

```
sort file1 file2 | uniq -c | awk '{ print $2"\t"$1 }'
```

Comment: The combine-and-sort case doesn't distinguish between two references in one file and one reference in each file -- and using two grep calls for what comm can do in one pass (and without having to load _either_ file fully into memory) seems a bit silly.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy How is two grep commands less efficient than two comm commands plus process substitutions of four sort commands?

Comment: Useless Use of Cat in your second example.  `sort` takes files directly.

Comment: +1 The second suggestion is definitely the easiest approach if there are no duplicates in `file1` or `file2`.  If there *are* duplicates, you could always do `sort <(sort -u file1) <(sort -u file2)` instead.

Comment: @kojiro look again -- I have one that only calls comm once and sort twice. And comm doesn't load either file fully into memory to process, doing only iterative line-by-line operations, making it far more efficient than grep, which loads file1. As for sort, it's capable of farming out very large inputs to temporary files, making it immune to out-of-memory conditions which feeding a very large file in as an `-f` argument to grep would hit.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy first of all, you added that second statement *after* making your comment about the grep approach. Second of all, *sort* certainly loads the entire file into memory, so you've lost anything you've gained from comm. Finally, you're still arguing that your two sorts plus one comm in nested process substitutions, finally processed by a bash loop, is more efficient than two greps. Care to make a benchmark for large and small inputs?

Comment: @kojiro yes, but my first one said up-front that it was known to be inefficient -- I was still testing the second one before editing it in. And no, GNU sort _doesn't_ load the file into memory if it's too large (see the `--buffer-size` argument) -- it uses temporary files to store sorted chunks (and then merges the temp files themselves) in that case. But yes, a benchmark would be interesting.

Comment: I'll grant, by the way, that there may well be a constant factor substantial enough here that the two-greps approach to be faster for small inputs. That said, because the "two sorts" you speak of happen in parallel, it's not entirely fair to compare them to two greps which happen only one after the other.

Comment: I've created a [generalizable benchmark script](https://gist.github.com/2791583) and implemented the comm and grep approaches for it. My results show that the grep method is significantly faster for large files, but not significantly slower for small inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, if you have python installed.
If you're familiar with Python and are interested in the solution, you only need a bit of formatting.

```
#/bin/python
f1 = open('file1').readlines()
f2 = open('file2').readlines()
f1_in_f2 = [int(x in f2) for x in f1]
for n,c in zip(f1, f1_in_f2):
    print n,c
```

Comment: If you were going to do this in Python, why wouldn't you use set arithmetic? There are native union and difference operations, and those will be far more efficient than a list comprehension doing the work.

Comment: Yes, but then you'll lose the original ordering.

Comment: It's still faster (presuming large enough inputs to overcome the constant factor) to have a set _and_ a list. `x in f2` is O(n) for lists.